# Rewrite acrive record query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

I have model `Issue` that `has_many :comments`, model `Comment` that `has_many :assets, as: :assetable, class_name: 'Comment::Asset'`, and model `Asset` that `belongs_to :assetable, polymorphic: true`

I need to get all the assets of the particular Issue.
My firt implementation is as following:

```
comments = Comment.where(issue_id: issue.id).ids
assets = Asset.where(assetable_id: comments)
```

However, it is obviously far from perfect. I believe, that this sould be rewritten using `joins` or something like this, but I fail to wrap my head around it and find a solution. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "manually" join the assets table with comments, as you cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association between them:

```
Asset
  .joins('JOIN comments ON comments.id = assets.assetable_id')
  .where(comments: { issue_id: issue.id })
```

However if a join isn't really needed, `where` plus `select` do the trick as well:

```
Asset.where(assetable_id: Comment.where(issue_id: issue.id).select(:id))
```

Notice there only one query is performed due to the `select(:id)` usage instead of `ids` (which extracts at once every id from the resulting rows):

```
SELECT assets.*
FROM assets
WHERE assets.assetable_id IN (
  SELECT comments.id
  FROM comments WHERE
  comments.issue_id = ?
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Now I understand it better!

Comment: Since `Asset` is polymorphic the `assetable_id` alone is insufficient to create a relationship, you will need to add a condition for the `assetable_type` column as well.